# Show 3 hidden divs at a time

Tags: jquery

I have a list of divs. I only let the 3 last show, and I need to show the 3 more at a time when pressing a button.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".container .item").each(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".item").slice(0, -3).hide();
  });

  $(".container .more").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".container").find(".item").slice(0, -6).show();
  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="more">Show 3 more</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

How can this be done? Keep in mind that there are multiple `.container` divs and I only want it to show from the container the `more` button is in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```js
$('.container').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.item:gt(2)').hide()
});
$('.container .more').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.item:not(:visible):lt(3)').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="more">Show 3 more</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="more">Show 3 more</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

This hides all the items divs except the first three per container, then upon clicking the more button it displays the next three not visible .more divs

Comment: Excellent answer! Thanks for sharing your knowledge with me :)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.container').each(function() {
        $(this).closest(".container").find(".item").slice(0,-3).hide();
    });
    $('.container .more').click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".container").find(".item:hidden").slice(-3).show();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="more">Show 3 more</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="more">Show 3 more</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
  <div class="item">Hello world</div>
</div>
```

This hides all the items divs except the first three per container, then upon clicking the more button it displays the next three not visible .more divs

Answer (score -2):

Think you are missing an event. Try wrapping it in this.

```
    $(document).ready(function(evt) {

});
```

Or take a look at this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yo3kk8uh/)

Comment: The code I provided were snippets. I have my code in document.ready().